# Custom bash autocomplete for git breaks other git autocomplete features

Tags: bash, autocomplete, git

I am trying to add autocompletion to `git commit` upon hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The autocomplete feature I am working on is based on a branch-naming convention. The convention is to append the PivotalTracker Id number to the end of the branch name, so a typical branch would look like `foo-bar-baz-1449242`.

We can associate the commits with the PivotalTracker card by prepending `[#1449242]` to the beginning of the commit message. I would like this to be auto-inserted if `git commit` is typed in and the user hits <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I have already done this here: https://github.com/tlehman/dotfiles/blob/master/ptid_git_complete

(and for convenience, here is the source code):

```
  function _ptid_git_complete_()
  {
    local line="${COMP_LINE}"                   # the entire line that is being completed

    # check that the commit option was passed to git 
    if [[ "$line" == "git commit" ]]; then 
      # get the PivotalTracker Id from the branch name
      ptid=`git branch | grep -e "^\*" | sed 's/^\* //g' | sed 's/\-/ /g' | awk '{ print $(NF) }'`
      nodigits=$(echo $ptid | sed 's/[[:digit:]]//g')

      if [ ! -z $nodigits ]; then
        : # do nothing
      else
        COMPREPLY=("commit -m \"[#$ptid]")
      fi
    else
      reply=()
    fi
  }

  complete -F _ptid_git_complete_ git
```

The problem is that this breaks the git autocompletion features defined in [git-autocompletion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)

How can I make this function compatible with git-autocompletion.bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `__git_complete` (defined in `git-autocompletion.bash`) to install your own function, and have your function fall back to the original function. Possibly like this:

```
function _ptid_git_complete_()
{
  local line="${COMP_LINE}"                   # the entire line that is being completed

  # check that the commit option was passed to git 
  if [[ "$line" == "git commit " ]]; then 
    # get the PivotalTracker Id from the branch name
    ptid=`git branch | grep -e "^\*" | sed 's/^\* //g' | sed 's/\-/ /g' | awk '{ print $(NF) }'`
    nodigits=$(echo $ptid | sed 's/[[:digit:]]//g')

    if [ ! -z $nodigits ]; then
      : # do nothing
    else
      COMPREPLY=("-m \"[#$ptid]")
    fi
  else
    __git_main
  fi
}

__git_complete git _ptid_git_complete_
```

Comment: Thank you! I did a little trial and error to get the right function in the `else` clause, but that did it!

Comment: Here is the finished script, I forked the original and added the changes you helped me with: https://github.com/tlehman/git/compare/ptid-autocomplete-42